# Restrict file types in liveagent

Tags: community, liveagent

I have implemented file sharing on my liveagent chat application.

I have added following line in my custom chat vf page. And now I am able to share file over chat from client side.

```
<liveAgent:clientChatFileTransfer />
```

Can we restrict the file type for client. Like I want that client will be only able to share text file.

Is it possible in salesforce ?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, unfortunately it's impossible now. I've asked the Salesforce support about that I got the next answer:

> I understand that you submitted a case regarding restricting types of
>   transferring files.
>
> I would like to apologize as the standard behavior currently is that
>   the file size limit is the same as the upload file size limit
>   (default, 5MB) and there is no limit on the format. You can do PDF,
>   JPEG, GIF, etc
>
> Live Agent file transfer uses the same file upload functionality
>   built-in in salesforce wherein All file types are supported, including
>   everything from Microsoft® PowerPoint presentations and Excel
>   spreadsheets, to Adobe® PDFs, image files, audio files, and video
>   files except that there is file size limit.
>
> Upload Files:
>   https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_uploading.htm&language=en

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that Salesforce officially does not support this. But you can restrict the file types through JavaScript.

If you do a view-source of the client chat window you can see Salesforce generate the below HTMl code for `<liveAgent:clientChatFileTransfer />` Visualforce component.

`<input id="fileSelectInput" name="file" type="file" />`

This is a normal file type input element with `id="fileSelectInput"`. So in JS you can get this element and implement your own logic to restric the file types.

Here is a working version of the JS code, you can put in the chat vf page. Update the file types as per your requirement.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">          
    var jq = $.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function(){
        alert("1");
        jq('#fileSelectInput').change(function () {
            var ext = jq('#fileSelectInput').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if(jq.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
                alert('This is not an allowed file type.');
                this.value = "";
            } 
        });             
    });    
</script>
```